# awk array that contains 0 prints as empty space

Tags: arrays, awk

To illustrate my issue, here is a simple example:

`cat file1.txt`

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

`cat file2.txt`

```
user1 0
user2 3
user3 8
user6 9
```

`awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next } { print $1, a[$1] ? a[$1] : "NA" }' file2.txt file1.txt`

```
user1 NA
user2 3
user3 8
user4 NA
```

I need the `0` to be printed after user1, but it's printing `NA` as if `user1` did not exit in `file2.txt`

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but why is this the case?

PS. I am aware that of the `grep -f` solution here, but I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong in the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When evaluating an expression as a Boolean condition, AWK considers a string whose numeric value is zero to be *false*, so you will always get "NA" for the users whose associated number is 0. (The same is true of the empty string, which would appear in the array if a user were listed in `file2.txt` with no number after their name at all.)

To reliably print all the numbers from `file2.txt`, you need to change the test condition from one that depends on the *value* of `a[$1]` to one that simply checks for the *presence* of the key `$1` in the array. This should work:

```
print $1, ($1 in a ? a[$1] : "NA")
```

That will only print "NA" if the key is missing from the array entirely.